# Convert Data from Columns to Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with data like the one below.

```
ID  Full Name   Apples  Mangoes Grapes
1     Name1      15       19    13
2     Name2      11       16    15
3     Name3      12       18    11
4     Name4      16       20    11
5     Name5      14       19    13
6     Name6      19       15    18
```

I wanted to convert it like this.

```
ID  Full Name   Fruits  Values
1   Name1       Apples  15
1   Name1       Mangoes 19
1   Name1       Grapes  13
2   Name2       Apples  11
2   Name2       Mangoes 16
2   Name2       Grapes  15
3   Name3       Apples  12
3   Name3       Mangoes 18
3   Name3       Grapes  11
4   Name4       Apples  16
4   Name4       Mangoes 20
4   Name4       Grapes  11
5   Name5       Apples  14
5   Name5       Mangoes 19
5   Name5       Grapes  13
6   Name6       Apples  19
6   Name6       Mangoes 15
6   Name6       Grapes  18
```

Is there any possibilities that it can be done in Microsoft SQL?

Comment: Another simple approach if the columns are known: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7fdda/2/0

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `UNPIVOT`:

```
select * from TableName
unpivot([Values] for Fruits in ([Apples], [Mangoes], [Grapes]))u
```

Comment: @jpw, is this prohibited?